# How can I stop this event from firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://www.sofiaclara.com/pick-your-own-raspberries/)

In the right sidebar, you'll notice that the last element runs with scrolling.

The problem is that does not stop ... go to the bottom of all.

[image]

I tried this function to accomplish the task

**CODE JS:**

```
   var aux=0;
   $("#text-3").addClass("follow-scroll");
   var _footerH=$("#footer-container").outerHeight();
   var _docH=$(document).height();
   var _scrollP= $(window).scrollTop();
   console.log("pozitie scroll",_scrollP);
   console.log("inaltime footer",_footerH);
   console.log("inaltime document HTML",_docH);
   var element = $('.follow-scroll'),
       originalY = element.offset().top;
       var topMargin = 20;
   element.css('position', 'relative');

     $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log(scrollTop);
        console.log("originalY:",originalY);
        console.log("Scrolltop:",scrollTop);
        console.log("topMargin:",topMargin);

        var y = scrollTop - originalY + topMargin;

       if(scrollTop < originalY) {

           console.log("nu s-a declansat evenimentul");

       }else {
       //aici trebe adaugat top la div
        aux=scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        $( '.follow-scroll' ).css( 'top', aux );
         if(scrollTop>6000)
         {
          var _div = $( ".follow-scroll" );
          var position = _div.position();
          var top2=aux;
           //aici trebuie sa primeasca ultimul top
           $( '.follow-scroll' ).css( 'top', aux );
         }
       }


     //  top=aux;
    //   console.log("top_nou:",aux);


    });
```

Can you help me solve this problem?
How can I stop this element at some point?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to this

```
 var aux = 0;
 $("#text-3").addClass("follow-scroll");
 var _footerH = $("#footer-container").outerHeight();
 var _docH = $(document).height();
 var _scrollP = $(window).scrollTop();
 console.log("pozitie scroll", _scrollP);
 console.log("inaltime footer", _footerH);
 console.log("inaltime document HTML", _docH);
 var element = $('.follow-scroll'),
     originalY = element.offset().top;
 var topMargin = 20;
 element.css('position', 'relative');

 $(window).on('scroll', function (event) {
     var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     console.log(scrollTop);
     console.log("originalY:", originalY);
     console.log("Scrolltop:", scrollTop);
     console.log("topMargin:", topMargin);

     var y = scrollTop - originalY + topMargin;

     if (scrollTop < originalY) {
         console.log("nu s-a declansat evenimentul");
     } else {
         //aici trebe adaugat top la div
         aux = scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
         if (scrollTop > 6000) {
             var _div = $(".follow-scroll");
             var position = _div.position();
             var top2 = aux;
             //aici trebuie sa primeasca ultimul top
         }else{
             $('.follow-scroll').css('top', aux);
         }
     }
 });
```

You will notice the that you should only set `$('.follow-scroll').css('top', aux);` if `scrollTop <= 6000` otherwise leave it where it is

Comment: I changed the code (you can inspect to see) but unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: Sorry, I missed something ... now I stop after 6000px

Comment: Any idea how I could stop this element footer fixed before?
Now I put an estimate ... but should stop just before the footer.
What would be the functional algorithms?

Comment: rather than `6000` use `$('#your-footer').offset().top`